# Authorization flow using signing and encryption with public/private keypair

Tags: dotnetopenauth

We would like to implement an authentication consumer using a REST service from a third party provider.

To retrieve userinformation they are only providing the authorization flow. This flow returns an URL to their system to redirect to, when the user authenticates in their system, they do a postback to our page including a token. With that token we can call their system again to retrieve the actual user information.

They require us to use a public private keypair (available via an url) to sign and encrypt all the JSON data (request and response objects are/need to be signed and encrypted). Their response claim will also be base64 encoded, signed and encrypted using RSA SHA-256.

Are there any examples on how we could implement the retrieval of the user information (claim) using dotnetopenauth?

Note that I'm completely new to OpenID and OAuth

Comment: Please post your work so far. See [ask] and [mcve] for help in writing a good question.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. For the moment there is no code yet, since I don't know what I should use to implement the explained scenario. Where should I start? Thanks a lot